# How Do You Rebuild In Android Studio After Modifying SDK Source Code?

Tags: android, android-studio, rebuild

I made a simple change to AbsListView.  When I run my app, breakpoints on the new lines are not hit.  Breakpoints in the same function can be hit.  It looks like the editor window is displaying what I wrote, but under the hood it is using the old version.  It's as if the new code was never recompiled.  How can I get the 2 in sync?

I have tried clean project, rebuild project, make project.  I am using Android Studio 1.0.2 on Windows.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code you have on your machine is not the same as what is actually run on the device, so you cannot make changes to OS classes and expect them to take effect.

The answer is, you cannot. You may want to write a new question to resolve the problem that you thought required this change to `AbsListView`.

Comment: Already done.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873449/how-can-i-prevent-activation-for-some-listview-items-when-the-selection-mode-is)